# Asp.net Mvc multiple file upload with ajax some errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I trying to multiple file upload in mvc with Jquery ajax but i have some problems.

[image]

Here its my Html design and codes..

```
<div id="fileinputdiv">
  <input type="file" name="mainfile" id="mainfile" onchange="OnValueChanged(this)">
</div>
<div id="tab_images_uploader_container" class="text-align-reverse margin-bottom-10">
  <span class="btn green fileinput-button">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                <span><a href="#" id="AddFile"> New Image... </a></span>
  </span>
  <a id="tab_images_uploader_uploadfiles" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="button" value="Upload Images" id="btnUpload" name="btnUpload" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Javascript codes...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var files = [];  // Creating array for list of files
function OnValueChanged(fileUploadItemId) {           
    var selectedvalue = $(fileUploadItemId).val();
    files.push(selectedvalue);

}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AddFile").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(" <input type='file' onchange='OnValueChanged(this)'>").appendTo("#fileinputdiv");
    })

    $("#btnUpload").on("click", function () {

        var fileData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);  
        }   
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Product/UploadFiles",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });

    })
});
```

And the finally my function..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                    string fname;

                    if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fname = file.FileName;
                    }

                    fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/"), fname);
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
                return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No files selected.");
        }
    }
```

My question is when i click the "Upload Files" button no any data sending with ajax to the UploadFiles() function i always getting "No files selected" errors but i tested with this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      alert(files[i]);
    }
```

i'm able to display all files which is selected. where is the problem that i could not find ?

Comment: I recommend you not to do this. In ASP.Net Core MVC you, since Web API has been integrated as part of ASP.Net, you may not be able to access files on Ajax request that way anymore. (Just in case you plan to upgrade). I recommend you to create a distinct page for uploads and display it either using an IFrame, or a new pop up window with toolbars, ect disabled. If you are interested, I share my solution with you.

Comment: Can you share your solution with me, please.

Comment: @Transcendent Hi can you help me for this ?

Comment: I've written an unobtrusive asynchronous uploader and pushing it to GitHub now, Will share the link and manual with you so you can easy upload your files.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Have you tried using this plugin? `http://malsup.com/jquery/form/`. I used it in my project and works just fine with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `Request.Files` with `request.Form.Files`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to use Ajax for asynchronous file upload for various reasons. One would be to experience problems with attaching FormData and getting it in your API, and the other would be to get error when accessing `HttpContext.Request.Form` especially in ASP.Net Core. My recommendation to you is to use the following if asynchronous upload is a REQUIREMENT, else you could do it the non-ajax way in a separate popup window.

Use the following Javascript code:

```
function uploadAsync(evt){
     if (evt.enctype == "multipart/form-data") {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Add the response to the desired tag by calling the xhr.responseText
            }
        };
        xhr.onprogress = function(progressEvent){
           // Update your progress here
        }
        xhr.open(evt.method, evt.action, true);
        xhr.send(new FormData(evt));
    }
}
```

This code may cause post back, in order to prevent it use `return false;` after calling the method:

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="your action API" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="uploadAsync(this); return false;"> 
   <input name="personalImage" type="file" />
   <input name="coverImage" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

now assuming:

```
public class FileHandlerController: Controller{

    [HttpPost]
    public String GetFileAndVerify(){
         var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
         // do the process on files
         return "We got them files";
    }
}
```

or you can use `IFormFile` in ASP.Net Core or `HttpPostedFile` in ASP.Net 4.

If you run into any problems when using this approach, let me know in the comment to provide you with more information and solve your problem.

**Update**

I have developed an unobtrusive version of this approach which you can find here: [GitHub](https://github.com/Vedadiyan/PannaCottaAsync/releases/tag/alpha.v.1)

here's the user manual:

```
<form async progress-bar-parent="pbarMain" progress-bar-name="pbar" response-parent="updArea" response="updElement" progress-bar-percentage="pbarPercent" dateset-ajax="true" action="/AdminArea/FilesAPI/PostFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm pull-left p-10">
         <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
         </span>
     </div>
</form>

<div id="pbarMain" class="progress" style="margin-top:20px; width:96%; margin-left:2%; position:relative; display:none;"></div>
<div id="updArea" class="input-group input-group-sm pull-left p-10" style="display:none;">
     <input id="updElement" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyText('#updElement')">Copy</button>
     </span>
</div>
```

To allow uploading files in multiple forms at the same time, include `allow-multi` in your form tag like `<form allow-multi class="..." ...>`. However, this may result in some UI problems as this version I have developed is still the alpha version.